# How to login on Trademap with Python?

Tags: python, authentication

I try to login on [here](https://trademap.org/Index.aspx). I have no idea how to deal with the popup Window. I found some answers but they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a popup window, just a hidden form. Anyway, you don't have to worry about it. Check the network activity, the login is being done via a POST to the url `https://mas-admintools.intracen.org/authentication/(S(qlklvpjzpt0xs213n4tus00b))/Login.aspx?lang_id=en&tool_id=2&toolKey=132104105110012030036115100121125135135126101027135102126027&username=trademaplight@intracen.org&referer=trademap.org&style=white&differedAuth=true&returnUrl=https%3a%2f%2ftrademap.org%2fLogin.aspx&anonymous=true&_cache=636676138695171367`

You could use something like python Requests and POST a username and password straight to that url. It will probably return you a cookie, and you use that for any other requests afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

trademap_mainpage_url = "https://www.trademap.org/Index.aspx"

login_data = {"PageContent_Login1_UserName": " ---------------", "PageContent_Login1_Password":" -------------"}
requests.post(trademap_mainpage_url, login_data)
```

I've found this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333506/module-object-not-callable-when-trying-to-log-into-webpage-using-requests-po).