# 'module' object not callable when trying to log into webpage using requests().post()

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to script a log-in into this website: https://www.trademap.org/Index.aspx

You will require log-in details but just indicate that you are from a developing country and you will have free access.

You will find the log-in button around the top right-hand corner of the webpage. It seems like that is no dedicated URL for the log-in.

The code that I wrote is as such:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

trademap_mainpage_url = "https://www.trademap.org/Index.aspx"

login_data = {"PageContent_Login1_UserName": " ---------------", "PageContent_Login1_Password":" -------------"}
requests().post(trademap_mainpage_url, login_data)
```

My login detail have been hyphened out.

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a9a30e4eb11b> in <module>
      1 login_data = {"PageContent_Login1_UserName": "-----------", "PageContent_Login1_Password":"----------"}
----> 2 requests().post(trademap_mainpage_url, login_data)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Again, login details have been hyphened out.

On a side note, I am completely new to web scraping, just started reading about it today so I apologize for my incompetence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not:

```
requests().post(url, data)
```

but instead:

```
requests.post(url, data)
```